# socket.emit not passing messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following js code

```
`var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require("path");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('*', function (req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/Public'));
});

app.use('/home',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/Public')));

//app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + 'index.html'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
   });
    socket.on('another-message', function (data) {
    socket.emit('not-news', { hello: 'world' });
  });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});`
```

I have the HTML code

```
   <html>
    <h1>working</h1>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { path :'/' +home});
        socket.on('connect',function(){
        socket.emit('message', 'Hello server');
      });
       socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
      });
    </script>
    <body>
       <p>display a message</p>
      </body>
    </html>`
```

I go to the page localhost:3000/home and i get my HTML page. But in the console i couldn't see any messages. Where am i wrong? please correct me.

Comment: please try this in html socket.emit('message',{ 'msg' :'Hello server'}); instead of socket.emit('message', 'Hello server');

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @abhyudit i dint get any error, but no message is passed between browserand node. Hence both console and browser are empty

Comment: Did you check the browser console and and terminal (where you run the server) for errors? If no errors are posted then something else would be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say that you didn't get any errors in console? I got an error. I'll paste a screenshot of this:

[image: Error]

Click on that to see where you've got errors.

I'll save you the time.

Change this line in index.html

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { path :'/' +home});
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

After that you'll get something like this:

[image: Success]

Comment: @SureshKrishna please accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: I wanted the connection for the specific path localhost:3000/home so i did var ioPath = "";
  iopath = '/' + 'home'+ '/socket.io'
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { path : iopath});              but in browser i get                                                                                  "GET http://localhost:3000/home/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LA2EDPs 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Why are you trying for a specific path? It doesn't work that way. You can use namespaces instead. http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/